# Can I show an object (subclass of QLabel ) created as needed? (the issue I have is deleting it)

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have created a label to show some info.. the way it works, if I need to show an image I set it on the label.

```
class PreviewLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    explicit PreviewLabel(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QLabel(parent)
    {
        this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
    }

protected:
    virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent *)
    {
        this->close();
    }
};

void showImageSlot()
{
    QImage preview = getSomeImage();
    if(preview.isNull())
        return;
    PreviewLabel* previewShow = new PreviewLabel();
    previewShow->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(preview));
    previewShow->show();
}
```

This has a memory leak though - the `PreviewLabel` object never gets deleted.
(Which is probably why it works.)

I tried to add a `previewShow->deleteLater();` after the `show()` and the image didn't show.
I also tried not to make it a pointer, but the image didn't show (see code below).
Technically it shows but gets killed instantly... because the program reaches the end of the `showImageSlot` function.

```
void showImageSlot()
{
    QImage preview = getSomeImage();
    if(preview.isNull())
        return;
    PreviewLabel previewShow;
    previewShow.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(preview));
    previewShow.show();
}
```

So the `previewShow` object needs a lifetime longer than that function... but how ?

I preferred not to make it a member variable - but I also tried to make it one (deleted in class destructor).

```
if(m_previewShow == NULL)
    m_previewShow = new PreviewLabel();
m_previewShow->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(preview));
m_previewShow->show();
```

This... crashes on first call.

How can I show it, preferably without having to make it a class member variable ?

I was thinking of making the object kill itself in the `leaveEvent` - is that possible ?

Edit - Two people have suggested the same thing - I add `this->deleteLater();` in the `leaveEvent`.
I tried and the program seems to run fine -

But I also ran it in Valgrind and the program crashes, the log file says

```
--15595-- memcheck GC: 32768 nodes, 30902 survivors ( 94.3%)
--15595-- memcheck GC: increase table size to 65536
==15595== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==15595==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==15595==    by 0x805D495: MainWindow::~MainWindow() (mainwindow.cpp:234)
==15595==    by 0x4E7ED02: qDeleteInEventHandler(QObject*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1)
```

(the referenced line number is at the end of the destructor of the main class containing `showImageSlot()` function)

Comment: You can walk with debugger, to handle a crash. For auto-deleting objects you may call `this->deleteLater()` in your `leaveEvent` handler.

Comment: @SaZ I didn't know an object can delete itself... It seems to work but when I run with Valgrind it crashes.

Comment: Not clear what you exactly want to achieve. Dow you want to show different images on the same label or each time to create and show a new label with the image and destroy it afterwards? In the latter case you can use a QTimer to destroy the label after required period of time. And I see this->close() in the mouse event - you can call this->deleteLater(); after that and your label will be destroyed on the mouse leaving.

Comment: @EvgenyS. - when processing some images somewhere else, I want at the end of processing to show the image, temporarily - but NOT on a timer - I don't know how long the user wants to look at it. So I made that class to close the label once the user moves his mouse off the label. As I mentioned in my comment to precious identical suggestion, it seems to work but if I run on valgrind it crashes. I will add that to the question.

Comment: You can put it into a QDialog, then connect the `finished` signal to `deleteLater`. QLabel is not designed to be a window of itself and it lacks the signals to be connected to `deleteLater`.

Comment: Or you can emit a signal in hideEvent or other events, can connect it to `deleteLater`

Comment: Don't create QLabel on stack and you won't get crash. Well, your initial code with `new`  then ok. The only you should add there is `deleterLater()` in `leaveEvent()`.

Comment: Regarding crashes with `m_previewShow`. Are sure that you set NULL to it in constructor? And this must be `QPointer` if you want to reuse it.

Comment: Why don't you hide/show it instead of delete/create it ? And @EvgenyS. is right about the NULL.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyS. I just tested it - and valgrind approves - I will mark it as answer if you write an answer.

Comment: @Ilya I don't know if I need to ever create it... So I thought I only create it if needed.

Comment: QPointer is only needed if anyone else could the delete label - and here I don’t see anyone who would do that.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Not exactly. If we reuse the same varible that can destroy itself elsewhere we need to know if it still exists or not. Without `QPointer` when we call `deleteLater` we invalidate the pointer in `m_previewShow`. Of course, this makes sence only in case we create/destroy the label each time as OP requested. If we would hide/show the label then QPointer is not required.

Comment: @EvgenyS. Right, I missed the part about deleteLater()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, list all variants.

First is as is initial code. Just add `deleteLater()` to `leaveEvent()` and the label will be destroyed when mouse leaves the widget.

```
class PreviewLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    explicit PreviewLabel(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QLabel(parent)
    {
        this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
    }

protected:
    virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent *)
    {
        this->close();
        this->deleteLater();
    }
};

void showImageSlot()
{
    QImage preview = getSomeImage();
    if(preview.isNull())
        return;
    PreviewLabel* previewShow = new PreviewLabel();
    previewShow->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(preview));
    previewShow->show();
}
```

Second, with member variable that destroys itself after mose leaving the widget. Note, that the member variable must be guarded with `QPointer` so you always know if it exists or not.

```
class PreviewLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    explicit PreviewLabel(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QLabel(parent)
    {
        this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
    }

protected:
    virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent *)
    {
        this->close();
        this->deleteLater();
    }
};

// somewhere in member declaration

// this should be QPointer in order to detect label destroy
QPointer<QLabel> m_previewShow;

...

void showImageSlot()
{
   if(!m_previewShow)
      m_previewShow = new PreviewLabel();
   m_previewShow->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(preview));
   m_previewShow->show();
```

}

Comment: This did not work. the only thing that worked was your noticing that, if I create the preview as a (pointer) member variable, I had to initialize it to NULL in constructor. the `this->deleteLater()` in any shape or form makes the program crash when I run it in Valgrind - so I cannot use it.

Comment: @Thalia At what moment the app crashes? Just after `deleteLater` or somewhen later? How many times you can see the image label popup?

Comment: The crash in Valgrind happens as soon as I start the program. I don't get to do anything that leads to showing the popup. I imagine they create and allocate their objects differently... Regardless, since I must be able to run it with Valgrind as well as stand-alone, even if that command is normally safe I cannot use it.

Comment: Like I mentioned in comments above - I cannot use `this->deletelater()`. What worked was, creating my preview as a class member variable (see my 3rd code snippet in question) - and you helped by reminding me to set it to NULL in constructor (I assumed it was so).